# Como obter as informações de um .CPL?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Eu queria fazer um programa que exibisse todos os itens do painel de controle. Pra isso eu preciso consultar algumas chaves do registro, mas tem programas que ainda usam arquivos cpl para armazenar as informações.

Fiquei sabendo que cpl são DLL's escritas em C++ mas eu não entendo muito bem de C++ pra entender a estrutura. Achei um tópico na MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144199(v=vs.85).aspx que mostra a estrutura dos .cpl mas eu não sei como fazer um intermédio entre o cpl, que é uma dll escrita em C++, com meu projeto em C#.

Queria que me dessem um exemplo de um código que analise o Assembly.cpl por exemplo, e retorne o nome do item no painel de controle, o texto de descrição e o ícone (se possível, extrair do assembly para uma pasta temporária; ou se for o caso, retornar o endereço do .ico).

Sei que é pedir de mais, mas se me ajudarem estarão me quebrando um galhão.

Comment: Veja se ajuda Enumerate and Host Control Panel Applets using C# (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6105/Enumerate-and-Host-Control-Panel-Applets-using-C) @marcelo-nascimento

Comment: A função `CPLApplet` é exportada em formato do C, então não há nada com C++ para se preocupar. Use `LoadLibrary` e `GetProcAddress` para obter a função de cada DLL. Por fim, é chamar-la tal como descrito na página linkada por você mesmo.

Comment: Valeu mesmo gente. Guilherme Bernal e Hub, vocês são gênios.

Answer (score 1):

Uma saída é usar as propriedades do arquivo. Se você pegar as propriedades do arquivo como cpl, virá algo como "Item do Painel de Controle" entretanto, se você copiar o CPL, alterando a extensão para DLL, você poderá pegar.

Peguei por exemplo o CPL: powercfg.cpl
Fiz uma cópia renomeando para powercfg.cpl.dll

Ao invés da descrição de arquivo anterior, agora veio: "Power Management Configuration Control Panel Applet"

Existe um arquivo na versão inglês do StackOverflow, podendo ser acessado por https://stackoverflow.com/a/3780110/2788478 que demonstra uma função (GetFileTypeDescription) utilizando a DLL do Windows shell32.dll.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abs